# How to speed up PowerQuery when working with large csv-Files as datasource

Tags: powerquery

I am working with a large csv-file as datasource in Excel 2019 with PowerQuery. I have a couple of joins. After a while the Worksheet starts to be unusable slow. Every time I change a filter, it reads the whole csv, what needs about a minute. It counts up to 150mb.

The csv is included and loaded to the model. Same for all other small datasources.

What can I do, that csv-File is hold in memory and speed will increase?

When I working on a query, the csv is read in again, after nearly every change. Its read in when I close and it is read in again, after it is closed.

Comment: At design time, temporary add a filter to retrieve 1000 top rows. Also google Table.Buffer. Without details it’s kind of difficult to know exactly what to do

Comment: Hello Ricardo. Thank you for the hint, I will read about Table.Buffers. I switched to a ODBC source against postgres. Things are better now, but PowerQuery performs still very poor. Basically I think it is worth to invest some time to get it run smooth, cause it could be a nice tool.

Comment: When I update the modell inside PowerQuery, the db-server goes up to 100% CPU for a long time. After the query has finished, the datatrasfer is pretty fast. I have no idea, how PowerQuery accesses the database, but even with about 3 Million rows, a query from any other application, do not need more than a few seconds. PowerQuery is doing a bad job in my opinion,

Comment: If you're doing transformations, look for query folding see https://radacad.com/not-folding-the-black-hole-of-power-query-performance

Comment: The article teach me how to view the native query. Its is a cascade of "select ... from (select ... from (select ... )))", for every step. It is not looking very effective.